# Force down error in a calculation app(use if/if else)

Tags: android

i have created an app that user places numbers into editexts and the app is making some calcs and displays a number..i have 7 lines with editexts .but the 7th editext is optional for the user to fill it(i added a checkbox and if the user select it the editext is visible,else its invisible..).i have a strange problem with my code and i would like to have your help..

firstly this is my code:

```
 apostoli.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                private AlertDialog show;

                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if ((vprosvasis.getText().toString() == " ")
                        || (vprosvasis.getText().length() == 0)
                        || (vprosvasis2.getText().toString() == " ")
                        || (vprosvasis2.getText().length() == 0)
                        || (vprosvasis3.getText().toString() == " ")
                        || (vprosvasis3.getText().length() == 0)
                        || (vprosvasis4.getText().toString() == " ")
                        || (vprosvasis4.getText().length() == 0)
                        || (vprosvasis5.getText().toString() == " ")
                        || (vprosvasis5.getText().length() == 0)
                        || (vprosvasis6.getText().toString() == " ")
                        || (vprosvasis6.getText().length() == 0)


                ) {

                                show = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setTitle("Error")
                                                .setMessage("Symplirwste olous tous vathmous prosvasis")
                                                .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();

                        } 


                    else if (((vprosvasis7.getText().toString() != " ")
                            || (vprosvasis7.getText().length() != 0)))
                {


                            float genikosvathmos = (float) (( new Float(vprosvasis.getText().toString())
                            + new Float(vprosvasis7.getText().toString())
                            + new Float(vprosvasis2.getText().toString())
                            + new Float(vprosvasis3.getText().toString())
                            + new Float(vprosvasis4.getText().toString())
                            + new Float(vprosvasis5.getText().toString()) + new Float(
                            vprosvasis6.getText().toString())) / 7);

                    float vprosvasisFloat = Float.parseFloat(vprosvasis.getText().toString());
                    float vprosvasisFloat2 = Float.parseFloat(vprosvasis2.getText().toString());
                    float vprosvasisFloat7 = Float.parseFloat(vprosvasis7.getText().toString());
                    float vprosvasisFloat5 = Float.parseFloat(vprosvasis5.getText().toString());

                    moria = (float) (((new Float((genikosvathmos * 8)+ (vprosvasisFloat * 1.3)+ (vprosvasisFloat2 * 0.7)) * 100)));
                    moria2 = (float) (((new Float((genikosvathmos * 8)+ (vprosvasisFloat7 * 1.3)+ (vprosvasisFloat5 * 0.7)) * 100)));

                    // Toast.makeText(thetiki.this, "Genikos vathmos"+moria ,
                    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // 1o pedio
                    show = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setTitle("moria")
                    .setMessage(            "1o pedio:  " + moria + "\n2o pedio:  "
                                            + moria + "\n3o pedio:  " + moria
                                            + "\n4o pedio:  " + moria
                                            + "\n5o pedio:  "+moria2)
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();

                }




                    else if ((vprosvasis.getText().toString()!= " ")
                        || (vprosvasis.getText().length() != 0)
                        || (vprosvasis2.getText().toString() != " ")
                        || (vprosvasis2.getText().length() != 0)
                        || (vprosvasis3.getText().toString() != " ")
                        || (vprosvasis3.getText().length() != 0)
                        || (vprosvasis4.getText().toString() != " ")
                        || (vprosvasis4.getText().length() != 0)
                        || (vprosvasis5.getText().toString() != " ")
                        || (vprosvasis5.getText().length() != 0)
                        || (vprosvasis6.getText().toString() != " ")
                        || (vprosvasis6.getText().length() != 0)
                        &&((vprosvasis7.getText().toString()== " ")
                        || (vprosvasis7.getText().length() == 0))


                )

                {

                    float genikosvathmos = (float) ((new Float(vprosvasis
                            .getText().toString())
                            + new Float(vprosvasis2.getText().toString())
                            + new Float(vprosvasis3.getText().toString())
                            + new Float(vprosvasis4.getText().toString())
                            + new Float(vprosvasis5.getText().toString()) + new Float(
                            vprosvasis6.getText().toString())) / 6);


                                 float vprosvasisFloat = Float.parseFloat(vprosvasis.getText().toString());
                                 float vprosvasisFloat2 = Float.parseFloat(vprosvasis2.getText().toString());


                                 moria=(float) (((new Float ((genikosvathmos*8)+(vprosvasisFloat * 1.3)+(vprosvasisFloat2 * 0.7))*100)));       

                                // Toast.makeText(thetiki.this, "Genikos vathmos"+moria , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                           show = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setTitle("moria")
                             .setMessage("1o pedio:  "+moria+"\n2o pedio:  "+moria+"\n3o pedio:  "+moria+"\n4o pedio:  "+moria+"\n5o pedio:  -")
                             .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();

                        } 

                } 

        });
```

`vprosvasis,vprosvasis2`..etc is the number into the editText.i have used 3 if/else.the first checks if the 6 first editexts are empty and if no there is an alert.the second would like to check if the `vprosvasis7` is not empty and then make a calculation.and finally,the third one want to check if the  `vprosvasis7` is used and then make a new calc..this is not working..specifically,the first if is working,the second works two,but if i havent filled the 7th editext,the 3rd if stacks and forces down my app..

your help would be really very helpfull..

EDIT

LogCat when the 7th editext is empty and i press the btn 'apostoli'

```
02-23 23:51:27.234: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5739): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 23:51:27.234: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5739): java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
02-23 23:51:27.234: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5739):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseFloat(FloatingPointParser.java:305)
02-23 23:51:27.234: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5739):     at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:291)
02-23 23:51:27.234: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5739):     at java.lang.Float.<init>(Float.java:111)
02-23 23:51:27.234: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5739):     at kostas.menu.moria.thetiki$8.onClick(thetiki.java:396)
02-23 23:51:27.234: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5739):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2461)
02-23 23:51:27.234: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5739):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8888)
02-23 23:51:27.234: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5739):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-23 23:51:27.234: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5739):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-23 23:51:27.234: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5739):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-23 23:51:27.234: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-23 23:51:27.234: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5739):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 23:51:27.234: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5739):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-23 23:51:27.234: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5739):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
02-23 23:51:27.234: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5739):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
02-23 23:51:27.234: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5739):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-23 23:51:27.249: WARN/ActivityManager(2944):   Force finishing activity kostas.menu.moria/.thetiki
02-23 23:51:27.300: INFO/(2944): dumpmesg > "/data/log/dumpstate_app_error.log"
```

Comment: Well.. What's the error you get? Attach your stacktrace as well.

Comment: the question is edited,including my logCat

Comment: thetiki.java:396 is the line in the 1rst else if:                         + new Float(vprosvasis7.getText().toString())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
float vprosvasisFloat7 = Float.parseFloat(vprosvasis7.getText().toString());
```

So, when the EditText is empty, you're essentially calling Float.parseFloat("");  The empty string is not a valid float, so the Float class throws an exception.

Check for the empty string before parsing.

```
if (vprosvasis7.getText().toString.equals("")) {
    float vprosvasisFloat7 = Float.parseFloat(vprosvasis7.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: float vprosvasisFloat7 = Float.parseFloat(vprosvasis7.getText().toString());
  .This is calling when the vprosvasis7 in not empty..Could you please be more specific in your answer,i think that is wrong...

Comment: I'm not sure where it is, due to no line numbers, but the stack trace is showing an error on thetiki.java line 396.  Whatever is being passed in on that line number to Float.parseFloat is causing the error.

Comment: thetiki.java:396 is the line in the 1rst else if: + new Float(vprosvasis7.getText().toString())

Comment: Ok. So it would seem that whatever vprosvasis7.getText().toString() is is not a valid float format, so the Float(String) constructor cannot parse it correctly.  Either print the string to the log or set a debug point to see what the value is and then safeguard the call against that input.